# HTML/CSS – How to get a perfect size match between a contained resized-image and a parent container with Firefox and Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have an issue with Firefox and IE in the code below : Everything is working extremely well with Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox and IE each image container does not respect the dimensions of its contained image. The image is resized proportionally with "height" command ; that does work. But IE and Firefox seem to take as a "width" value for the container of the image the original width of the jpeg file. How could we get a perfect result as in Chrome and Safari (with the contained image and its parent-container getting the same width and height each other) ?

Here is the HTML code :

```
<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="thegallery">
<div class="eachimage"><img src="images/image-1.jpg" /><div class="rollovertxt"><p>Caption</p></div><div class="rolloverbg"></div></div>
<div class="eachimage"><img src="images/image-2.jpg" /><div class="rollovertxt"><p>Caption</p></div><div class="rolloverbg"></div></div>
<div class="eachimage"><img src="images/image-3.jpg" /><div class="rollovertxt"><p>Caption</p></div><div class="rolloverbg"></div></div>
</div>
```

Here is the Css code :

```
.thegallery {
position:absolute;
top:6em; bottom:4em;
left:50%;
white-space:nowrap;
background-color:#36F;
z-index:1;
}

.eachimage {
position:relative;
height:100%; /* Full height of div.gallery */
display: inline-block;
margin-right:1em;
background-color:#63F;
}

.eachimage img {
height:100%; /* Full height of div.eachimage */
width:auto;
}

.eachimage:hover .rollovertxt { visibility:visible; }
.eachimage:hover .rolloverbg { visibility:visible; }

.rollovertxt {
position: absolute;
left:0.5em;
top:0.5em;
width:160px;
white-space:normal;
color:#FFF;
visibility:hidden;
z-index:3;
background-color:#F0F;
}

.rolloverbg {
position: absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
visibility:hidden;
z-index:2;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: 0.5;
background-color:#000;  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add web-kit, which is responsible for maintaing the size and position in different platfrom?

Comment: Dear Milan, I'm not sure of what you mean by webkit? Here the issue doesn't seem to come from any other commands than "height" or "display:inline-block" ?

Comment: Chris: Why don't you use the dev tool to disable and add style rules to elements, until you get the desired affect? We could post you a corrected css, but then you would not learn anything. see this link http://bigemployee.com/4-simple-techniques-to-quickly-debug-and-fix-your-css-code-in-almost-any-browser/ If you are going to write code you have to be able to debug it too.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that's what I try to do. I found where the problem was coming from yesterday : the problem was that Firefox and IE don't process correctly a relative "height" of an element with "em" positioning at top and bottom (Chrome and Safari do). Both browsers show a weird reaction then, keeping the actual width of the image file as a reference to give a size to the container. I had to add a calc() function in the css to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. It seems the problem was coming from the fact Firefox and IE do not process correctly (as Chrome and Safari would do) a relative "height" of an element when you just give these two browsers an "em" top and bottom positioning of that element. I fixed the problem by adding a calc() function (height = 100% - ((top-position expressed in "em")+(bottom-position expressed in "em"))).